# JavaFX using syntax <>.

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

Iam new to Java GUI; the usage of "<>" is new to me. Can someone explain from the code below as used in the EventHandler? Also, is there a way to avoid using it?

```
btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
```

Comment: That's the syntax used in generics types (parametric polymorphism), http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid it by using lambdas or method references with Java8